# Mostrar una fecha en un formato y almacenarla en otro (Datepicker en Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, date, datepicker

Estoy trabajando en laravel y quiero mostrar en mi campo Bootstrap Datepicker una fecha en un formato (dd / mm / yyyy) pero quiero almacenarlo en formato (yyyy / mm / dd).

¿Hay alguna propiedad en Datepicker para hacer eso? este es mi input:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="fecha_nac"></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control CalendarioDP" 
         name="fecha_nac" placeholder="Colocar fecha"
         value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%d/%m/%Y') }}">
</div>
```

Mi Script:

```
<script>
    $('.CalendarioDP').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "es",
    });
</script>
```

Cuando dejo el formato en el script de esta manera, la fecha se muestra y se almacena en un formato (dd / mm / yyyy)

[image: Mostrando la fecha en el formato indicado]

[image: Se guarda de al reves, se muestra en el primer campo tipo Date]

Quiero almacenarlo en (yyyy / mm / dd).

He usado "Torzer DateTime Mutator" y "protected $ dates", pero quiero saber si existe una propiedad DaterPicker simple para declarar una sola vez en el script y no especificar cada campo que quiero convertir como en Torzer

Comment: O sea, ¿quieres que visualmente sea dd / mm / yyyy pero cuándo llegue al servidor llegue como yyyy / mm / dd?

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez es correcto, exactamente eso quiero hacer, ya intenté con mutadores pero quiero saber si existe alguna propiedad que se pueda modificar en Datepicker

Answer (score 1):

una solucion es que puedes hacer es cuando pases los valores al controlador separarlo de la siguiente manera y luego unirlo:

- $fecha = "2006/05/04";
- $ano = substr($fecha, -10, 4);
- $mes =substr($fecha, -5, 2);
- $dia = substr($fecha, -2, 2);

y luego unirlo a otra variable php, para que lo tengas el formato que tu quieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo el punto de mi pregunta es la reducción de código, de igual manera muchas gracias :D